# ¿Como evitar que se haga captura de pantalla en mi activity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, screenshot

Tengo contenido en una activity (imagen) la cual tiene la opción de descargar, al descargar la imagen mostrara un anuncio (1 cada 2 min)...

Quiero evitar que los usuarios hagan captura de pantalla en esa activity o la aplicación y así deban descargarlo directamente desde el boton asignado.

No tengo código creado para esa función ya que no he encontrado como hacerlo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Coloca esto: `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` antes de `setContentView` en tu Activity